# Programming is asking for input twice

Tags: java, methods, boolean-operations

I'm having some troubles with the beginning of this program.
It's supposed to take a number and determine whether or not it is perfect.
Currently I have it asking how many numbers to check, whenever I input any positive number, it asks again.
AND, whenever I input a negative number for the second question, the program ends and doesn't prompt again.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class aermel_Perfect
{
public static void main ( String args [] )
{
    int gN = getNum();
    int gP = getPerfect();
}


public static int getNum() //Get amount of numbers to check
{
Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
System.out.print( "How many numbers would you like to test? " );
int count = input.nextInt();
int perfect = 1;
boolean vN = validateNum(count, perfect);
return count;
}   

public static boolean validateNum( int count, int perfect  ) //Check if number is valid
{
if (( count <= 0) || ( perfect <= 0))

{ 
    System.out.print( "Non-positive numbers are not allowed.\n");
}



else 
{
    return true;
}
return false;


}
public static int getPerfect() //Gets the numbers to test
{
Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
int perfect = -1;
int count = getNum();
System.out.print("Please enter a perfect number: " );
perfect = input.nextInt();
boolean vN = validateNum(perfect, count);
return perfect;
}
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks to make the logic flow easier to understand.   2) Code on SO needs only 1 line of white space at most, and then only rarely. 3) `getNum()` is called from 2 places.

Comment: 4) `aermel_Perfect` Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently. (But see point (3) for the fix).

Comment: @user1834819 : getNum() , you are calling this method again in the second method , then it is supposed to execute twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `while` loop in your `get` methods e.g. to repeatedly ask for input until a valid number is entered.

```
    public static int getNum() //Get amount of numbers to check
    {
      Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
      System.out.print( "How many numbers would you like to test? " );
      int count = input.nextInt();
      int perfect = 1;
      boolean vN = validateNum(count, perfect);
      while(!vN ){
          System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again");
          count = input.nextInt();
          vN = validateNum(count, perfect);
      }
      return count;
    }
```

Simiilarly, update the `getPerfect` method and remove `int count = getNum();` statement from this method.

**EDIT:**  To repeatedly ask for perfect number `count` times, update your main method as below:

```
   public static void main ( String args [] )
   {
      int gN = getNum();
      for(int indx=0; indx <gN; indx++){
         int gP = getPerfect();
         //use your gP numbers in the way you want
      }
   }
```

**EDIT1:** To call `How many numbers would you like to test? "` tow times, I think you can simply call your `getNum()` method two times in the main method as below:

```
   public static void main ( String args [] )
   {
      int gN = getNum();//first call
      gN = getNum(); //second call
      int gP = getPerfect();
   }
```

Comment: Also, you don't need to call `getNum()` method in your `getPerfect` method.

Comment: @RohitJain: Good point. I didn't look at the `getPerfect` method.

Comment: @YogendraSingh I changed my code to include the while statement in `getNum`. However, I would need this portion to output the original question again. Meaning, I can't just put the question in, I need it to just start over basically.

Comment: @user1834819: You mean, you want to print `How many numbers would you like to test?`, when user enters invalid number? If so, change the text in the `Sysout` inside the while loop with the same message. If no, please help me understand your question little better.

Comment: @YogendraSingh This fixed my second question. Back to my first question, when the program originally asks `How many numbers would you like to test?`, if the input is valid, it will ask the same question again. If I put another valid input in, the program will continue to run.

Comment: @user1834819 I am still missing something in your first question.  I updated the answer with my current understanding. Let me know, if you are looking for something different.

Comment: @YogendraSingh I do appreciate you answering my third question. I apologize that I may be a little confusing. If I were to run the program, the first thing it asks is `How many numbers would you like to test?` as long as I input a valid positive number, it will output `How many numbers would you like to test?` again. Asking the same question, for the same value.

Comment: @user1834819 Third question? Is your first still left? If yes help me understand your question.

Comment: @YogendraSingh I was just saying that you answered a question I had not even asked yet. Yes, my first question is still unanswered.

Comment: @user1834819: I am really having hard time understanding your first question. Due to your low reputation, I am unable to invite to chat. Check if the updated answer helps you?

Comment: @YogendraSingh I apologize for the confusion. If you could please view this link: http://i.imgur.com/de4kW.png I am simply wondering why the program is asking for the number twice.

Comment: @user1834819: Last edited answer should do the same. Did you try? As adviced earlier, remove `int count = getNum();` from `getPerfect` method.

Comment: @YogendraSingh I appreciate the assistance, the issues are resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = getNum();
System.out.print("Please enter a perfect number: " );
perfect = input.nextInt();
```

You get two numbers here.

Comment: How does the getPerfect statement mess with the getNum statement?

Comment: It doesn't - it uses it though. `getNum` calls `nextInt()` and `getPerfect` also calls `nextInt()`. This would create two inputs.